# How to mark part of a text as quoted in Telegram sendMessage Bot API?

Tags: telegram, markup

Recently Telegram has provided [the ability to quote texts](https://telegram.org/blog/reply-revolution#quote-formatting):

[image]

I want to send a message using Telegram Bot API using `html` as `parse_mode` but I cannot find any mention of how to do it using html tags in [official docs.](https://core.telegram.org/api/entities)

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **quote a specific part of a message** (for it to appear as a clickable object).
You can modify **[reply_parameters](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replyparameters)** in method **[sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)**.

I didn't manage to build a post request that sends message with such quote, but here is how it looks using **Aiogram3**:

```py
from config import TOKEN, chat_id, message_id
from aiogram import Bot, types
import asyncio

bot = Bot(token = TOKEN)

asyncio.run(
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text='Quoting the message!',
        reply_parameters=types.ReplyParameters(
            chat_id=chat_id,
            message_id=message_id,
            quote='this'
        )
    )
)
```

> Unfortunatelly, I can't post screenshot to show how it works...
> That's my first ever stackoverflow answer

---

You can also simply **format message like as if it has a quote**.

If you desire to use **HTML** formatting, there is a `<blockquote>` tag.

```
This is not a quote
<blockquote>But this is!</blockquote>
```

Or you can set parse_mode to **MarkdownV2** and use the format below:

```
This is not a quote
> But this is!
```

That's how it looks with **Aiogram3**:

```py
from config import TOKEN, chat_id, message_id
from aiogram import Bot, types
import asyncio

bot = Bot(token = TOKEN)

asyncio.run(
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text=(
            'This is not a quote\n'
            '<blockquote>But this is!</blockquote>'
        ),
        parse_mode='HTML'   
    )
)
```

---

#### All the formatting info on Telegram is [provided here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options)!

Answer (score 0):

The formatting options providide by the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options) do not include this functionality yet.